# Cannot convert type bool to int

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I lost my source code and had to decompile from a DLL and am receiving the following error in the code of a LINQ to SQL DataContext class.

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'int'

It looks like VS generated code that is using int instead of bool for some strange reason. See starred line below. What should I do to fix this casting error? It's used over a hundred times in this class.

```
    public int? OrderBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OrderBy;
        }
        set
        {
            int? nullable = this._OrderBy;
            int? nullable1 = value;
            **if ((nullable.GetValueOrDefault() != nullable1.GetValueOrDefault() ? 1 : (int)(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue)) != 0)**
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._OrderBy = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("OrderBy");
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
The answer to this question is "get a better decompiler." The code above was generated by Telerik Just Decompile. ILSpy generates code tthat actually makes sense. in this instance:

```
    [Column(Storage = "_OrderBy", DbType = "Int", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never), DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public int? OrderBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OrderBy;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._OrderBy != value)
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._OrderBy = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("OrderBy");
            }
        }
    }
```

This question should probably just be deleted. Advise in comments.

Comment: It looks like you just want `if(this._OrderBy != value)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
if ((nullable.GetValueOrDefault() != nullable1.GetValueOrDefault()) || (nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue))
```

that should give the same result as what you had, but is a lot more readable.

Comment: The problem was the `(int)(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue)`.  That's casting a `bool` to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly cast a `bool` to an `int`:

```
(int)(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue) //invalid
```

but you can use `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
Convert.ToInt32(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue) //valid
```

So your code should be:

```
if ((nullable.GetValueOrDefault() != nullable1.GetValueOrDefault() ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue)) != 0)
```

However, I think you can just do a straightforward comparison due to "lifted" operators. From the C# Spec:

> For the equality operators == [and] != a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

So you could just use:

```
if (nullable != nullable1)
```

Which of course means you can elide the `nullable` and `nullable1` variables altogether and use

```
if (this._OrderBy != value)
```

Comment: The problem is that they are casting a `bool` to an `int` with this `(int)(nullable.HasValue != nullable1.HasValue)`

Comment: Agreed, hence my `You can't directly cast an int to a bool` and the change to `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: No the issue is casting a `bool` to an `int`, not an `int` to a `bool`.

Comment: Sorry @juharr, I misread what you'd written and I'd described it back to front in my answer (although the fix was correct?). I've updated it now to (hopefully) be clearer.

Comment: Yes, that looks better, though converting a `bool` to an `int` to compare it to and `int` in an `if` statement seems really awkward.

Comment: Yep, I completely agree. I would go with the last line in my answer personally.

Comment: Or even better would just be `if(this._OrderBy != value)` as I see no reason for those local variables.  Ha, I guess we're thinking alike.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this close to what a human would have written (instead of a decompiler).

Not sure why OrderBy is a int?, but left that alone...

**EDIT**

Also note that the conditional operator in your post returned 1 when true and a bool when false.  After fixing the issue in your post (can't convert bool to int), you'd be getting a can't convert int to bool error.

```
int? _OrderBy;
public int? OrderBy
{
    get
    {
        return _OrderBy;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((_OrderBy.GetValueOrDefault() != value.GetValueOrDefault()) || (_OrderBy.HasValue != value.HasValue))
        {
            SendPropertyChanging();
            _OrderBy = value;
            SendPropertyChanged("OrderBy");
        }
    }
}
```